# Offline python plugin installation for Netbeans?

Tags: python, netbeans

I have a latest windows netbeans version (6.9.1) and i want to instal a python plugin for it. I have no problems on a computer that has internet connection, it's just tools->plugins->Available. But i have another computer that don't have internet connection available :(. Is it possible to install python addin for it? Where i can download the .nbm file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check:

> /home/username/netbeans-6.9.1/php/update/download

I tested it with the php plugin so you should check the python directory. Or if you are using windows you may find somewhere similar.

If no .nbm file there, you may try:

> Uninstall python plugin from the other computer, and reinstall it. Don't restart NetBeans immediately, check the directory, and copy all the files.

Answer (score 1):

Click Tools -> Plugins, and in the plugin dialog box, click the "Downloaded" tab. On that tab, click the "Add Plugin" button, which will open a file browser dialog box, allowing you to give Netbeans the location of your downloaded .nbm file. Easy!

You can find Netbeans plugins here: http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/